# Grammaticality of 'a proposal that is discussed in a meeting and a vote is taken on it'

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

Is the phrase

> 1. 'a proposal that is discussed in a meeting and a vote is taken on it'

grammatically correct, and if so, could anyone please explain to me how, as I fail to see it. After the conjunction 'and' here I would expect an additional relative clause with respect to 'that', e.g.

> 2. 'a proposal that is discussed in a meeting and on which a vote is taken'

Comment: What you have is two sentence fragments. They may or may not be grammatical if put into the context of complete sentences.

Answer (score -1):

Both of your versions are ungrammatical, I think.

That is because you are saying *"is discussed"*. If the meeting *is* going on at the time when this phrase is being said, then you should have *"that is being discussed in a meeting"*. Also, it seems that the "meeting" is a specific or definite event in this case, and therefore it should take *"the"*; if its a specific proposal you are talking about you should use *"the"*.

> 1(a).*"This is **the** proposal that **was** discussed in **the** meeting [earlier today/yesterday], and a vote **was** taken on it."*

This is the first version. I changed the tense to fit *"discussed"*. In the second independent clause, *"it"* is referring to the "proposal". Note the use of comma.

This one works too (different tense of the same version):

> 1(b).*"This is **the** proposal that **is being** discussed in **the** meeting [right now], and a vote **will be** taken on it [by the end of the meeting]."*

On to the second version now (the one you suggested):

> "a proposal that is discussed in a meeting and on which a vote is taken"

This has the same problem as before. If you change the articles, and phrase it like the first rephrased version, it should look like this:

> 2.*"This is **the** proposal that **was** discussed in **the** meeting [earlier today/yesterday] and on which a vote **was** taken."*

This is fine too. Note the comma is no longer needed here.